# Neo4j strings not being passed to next step for processing

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this query:

```
WITH split("what is porsche",' ') as instr
MATCH (a)-[rels*]->(b)
WHERE a.name=instr[0] and b.name STARTS WITH 'outcome'
WITH [r IN rels | [STARTNODE(r).name]] AS steps
WITH [k in steps where size(steps)=3] as ka
RETURN ka limit 1
```

However, I want the size(steps)=3 be replaced with size(steps)=size(instr), where 'instr' is the input string passed in the first step.  I seem to be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `instr` to the next context in the first `WITH`, like this:

```
WITH split("what is porsche",' ') as instr
MATCH (a)-[rels*]->(b)
WHERE a.name=instr[0] and b.name STARTS WITH 'outcome'
WITH instr, [r IN rels | [STARTNODE(r).name]] AS steps
WITH [k in steps where size(steps)=size(instr)] as ka
RETURN ka limit 1
```

Comment: Great! Hey, I have an extension to this - right now without the LIMIT, it gives me two outputs - one of length 3 (correct) and another of length 0.  Can we eliminate the length 0 output without using LIMIT.

Comment: @ugp Try `WITH split("what is porsche",' ') as instr
MATCH (a)-[rels*]->(b)
WHERE a.name=instr[0] and b.name STARTS WITH 'outcome'
WITH instr, [r IN rels | [STARTNODE(r).name]] AS steps
WITH [k in steps where size(steps)=size(instr)] as ka
WHERE ka > 0
RETURN ka`

Comment: Super! I was able to eliminate the 0 length line.

Comment: Hey, how would i find the index value of a string within a list - for example WITH split ("what is porsche",' '), how would I find the position of 'porsche' as 3? Tks

Comment: @ugp I believe that is a good idea to make a new question instead of use the comments for it. This way the whole community can help you and other users with the same problem can take advantage of the answers. Ok? :)

Comment: @ugp Also, if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.